# How much air movement is need to produce a given thrust force?

Tags: kinematics

A rocket engine produces a chosen thrust force measured in Newtons.

This is done by moving air, and given the density, volume, and velocity of air, we can calculate kinetic energy and power directly.

But Joules are not Newtons. How do I connect these calculations? If my rocket is to produce my chosen thrust force, how much and how quickly does the air need to move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not air that it is being pushed, it is the exhaust gases.

There are two ways to compute the thrust:

1. Momentum conservation: the rate at which momentum is given to the exhaust gas must be equal and oposite the force on the rocket by Newton's third law. As a result
   $$
   F_{\rm thrust} = \dot m v_{\rm exhaust},
   $$
   where $\dot m$, the rate a which fuel is being converted  to hot high-pressure  exhaust gas, has units of ${\rm kg.s}^{-1}$. Then ${\rm kg s}^{-1}$ times m s$^{-1}$ gives units of Newtons.
2. Force balance: The  force on the rocket is due to the fact gas pressure in the combustion chamber is pushing on all the walls of the chamber, but *not* on the area of the hole through which the exhaust gas is escaping. In the  hole, the pressure is acting only on the gas, which is not attached to the rocket. As a  consequence
   $$
   F_{\rm thrust}=c P_{\rm chamber} A_{\rm nozzle}
   $$
   where $P_{\rm chamber}$ is the pressure of the hot gas in the combustion chamber and $A_{\rm nozzle}$ is the area of the hole (i.e the throat of the nozzle) and $c>1$ is a correction  due the fact that there is also unbalanced gas pressure on the walls of the expanding part of the nozzle. The gas continues to accelerate in the expansion part of the nozzle   until it reaches $v_{\rm exhaust}$ as it leaves the nozzle and no longer exerts a force on the rocket.

Comment: Does this analysis hold for helicopters?

Comment: No -- but you asked about rockets.

Comment: Since they both operate on "making gas move" I would naively expect an equal amount of thrust produced by the same expulsion of gas in both cases. I only care about the experience of an external observer hit by the thrust force, and how much work/energy/power the device requires to operate. How are a rocket and helicopter different in that sense?

Comment: A rocket does not need air, a helicopter does. A helicopter works like an aircraft.  In an aircraft there is no computationally direct relation between the energy given to the air and the momentum given to it. Even if we ignore friction drag, we can get the same lift with less drag by control of the wingtip vortices, or in general how the circulation is shed along the wing. How an aircraft generates lift  is complicated.  In principle if not in practice, how a rocket works is easy to understand.